# Problema com loop em array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loop, for

Quando tento executar o loop, nem se quer entrar no for, já verifiquei e o array com o objeto não está vazio, mas não executa o loop... Alguma ideia?

```
var caminho = [];

$.get("http://localhost/crocs/arquivo.json", function(data) {

    data = typeof data == 'string' ? JSON.parse(data) : data;

    data.forEach(function(elementoDaArray) {

        skuid = elementoDaArray.SkuId;
        valor = elementoDaArray.Valor;
        letra = elementoDaArray.Letra;
        imagem = elementoDaArray.Imagem;

        caminho.push({
            img: imagem,
            id: skuid
        })
    });
});


for (var i = 0; i < caminho.length; i++) {
    console.log(products[i].img);
}
```

Comment: pode colocar um exemplo do valor de `data`?

Comment: {"SkuId":"331","Valor":"9.90","Letra":"A","Imagem":"10006994_001UNI"} esse é o json que retorna através do $.get

Comment: Luiz ele é um simples objeto não um array, por isso o `forEach` não vai funcionar

Comment: Tente, antes do `forEach` executar isso pra vc ver: `skuid = data.SkuId;`

Answer (score 0):

$.get é uma função assíncrona, ela demora um tempo para buscar a resposta do seu endereço, mas o código não espera a função terminar para continuar rodando.
No caso, você está chamando $.get, e então tentando ler o array antes mesmo de preenche-lo, se você quiser continuar com o seu código apenas depois de receber a resposta de $.get, coloque seu loop dentro da função.
Outras alternativas são trabalhar com callbacks ou promises.

Comment: Andre vc está enganado, ele está tratando o retorno dentro da função de *callback* que é o segundo parâmetro do `get`, ou seja, quando retorna sucesso, veja a documentação caso tenha dúvida: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Sim, o retorno é tratado dentro da função de callback, porém o loop (for, não o forEach) está fora da função, ou seja.
1- $.get é chamado.
2- o loop for é executado.
3- o callback de $.get é executado.
Nessa ordem.

Comment: @RicardoPontual o que o Andre escreveu está correto, em que parte achas que ele está enganado?

Comment: Olá, li agora e vi com calma realmente está certo, porque o @Andre está se referindo o `for` que está fora do *callback*, tinha entendido que ele estava se referindo ao outro loop, que por sinal de acordo com o json de exemplo não vai funcionar, pois não é um array, minhas desculpas :)